# Incorrect redirect link (spotify auth in expo app)

Tags: react-native, expo, spotify

The problem is that the built app doesn't connect to spotify. But it works in dev mode.
Here is the context:
we have react native expo app
trying to connect to spotify via useAuthRequest from expo-auth-session (uses Linking under the hood).
sign-in-container.js:

```
import SignIn from './sign-in-component.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {compose} from "ramda";
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {isLogged} from "../../features/user-authentication/user-authentication-reducer";
import {signIn} from "../../features/user-authentication/user-authentication-saga";
import withGradient from "../../HOCs/with-gradient/with-gradient";
import {makeRedirectUri, useAuthRequest} from "expo-auth-session";
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isLogged: isLogged(state),
});
const redirectUrl = makeRedirectUri();
const clientId = '***';
const discovery = {
    authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
    tokenEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
};
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, {signIn}),
    withGradient,
)(({ isLogged, signIn, navigation }) => {
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
        {
            clientId: clientId,
            scopes: ['user-read-email', 'playlist-modify-public'],
            usePKCE: false,
            redirectUri: redirectUrl,
        },
        discovery
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
            const { code } = response.params;
            signIn(code);
        }
    }, [response]);
    const handlePressSpotifyButton = () => {
        promptAsync().then(() => {
            navigation.navigate('Onboarding')
        });
    };
    return <SignIn isLogged={isLogged} onPressSpotifyButton={handlePressSpotifyButton}/>;
});
```

And getting warning when start the project in dev mode (yarn start):

> Linking requires a build-time setting scheme in the project's Expo
> config (app.config.js or app.json) for production apps, if it's left
> blank, your app may crash. The scheme does not apply to development in
> the Expo client but you should add it as soon as you start working
> with Linking to avoid creating a broken build. Learn more:
> https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/

Without scheme it doesn't start via expo publish/expo build
Adding 'exp' as scheme for app.json config

```
"scheme": "exp"
```

After publishing get an error `incorrect redirect link`

redirection link in app:

- started locally: exp://192.168.0.159:19000 (works)
- published: exp://exp.host/@expo-user-name/my-app (incorrect)

How does the redirection link should look like to work not only in dev mode? Is adding 'exp' as scheme is correct?